# Leaflet layer control improperly selects basemaps when displaying multiple maps

Tags: leaflet, basemap, layer-control

As described [on github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6618), there seems to be an issue in Leaflet 1.4.0 when displaying multiple maps on a same page: base layers aren't properly selected.
In Leaflet 0.7.2 however, this seemed to work fine.

The following fiddles demonstrate the issue:
Leaflet 0.7.2 http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/fvy8aq37/2/ --> the base layers are correctly selected in both map controls
Leaflet 1.4.0 http://jsfiddle.net/sc28/9j3hstgx/ --> the base layers are only selected in the second map; when a base map is clicked in either map control, it gets deselected in the other.

Does anyone know of a solution or workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In your nonworking fiddle you are using version 1.4.0 of `leaflet.js`, but version 0.7.2 of `leaflet.css`.

I tried with correct version of CSS and it works OK.